# Are sidepots created at each turn, or at the end of the round?

Tags: side-pots

Im wondering, in hold'em, when sidepots are created/calculated, is it at the end of each player's turn or at the end of the round?

thanks!

Comment: You'll find the relevant information in the noted question. In short though, I believe it's created at the end of a players turn, assuming of course that a side pot is evn possible at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sidepots are created at the end of the round (preflop, flop, turn and river).

Because each player has the amount of chips that he put into the game in front of himself. And as soon as the round ends and the dealer collects all the chips the dealer has to build sidepot(s).

```
Example:

P1 has $500
P2 has $1000
P3 has $1000

We are in flop:

P1 bets $250.
P2 calls.
P3 raises to $750.
P1 calls (and goes allin).
P2 calls.
Dealer collects all chips and builds a mainpot of $1500 (3x$500) and a sidepot of $500 (2x$250).

Now we are in turn and only P2 and P3 play for the sidepot.
```

Comment: Had to edit the post because mixed up meaning of turn and round. Hope answer is more clear now.